# Meaning of ~られし form

Tags: meaning, auxiliary-き

```
悪魔の力を授かった故に、
定められし死をも超える存在と
なるのか…
```

Why there's し in 定められし?

Is it some kind of old-fashioned form?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/%e9%82%82%e9%80%85%e3%81%9b%e3%81%97%e7%98%b4%e7%82%8e-what-does-the-%e3%81%9b%e3%81%97-part-mean/75104#75104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

感覚的には下の用例かなあ。
俳句や短歌、詩などでは現代文でも使う。散文ではめったに使わない。

助動詞「し」の完了の用法：動作が完了して、その結果が存続している意を表す。…ている。…てある。https://weekly-haiku.blogspot.com/2011/11/blog-post.html